# "Element click intercepted" Element overlapping element

Tags: python, selenium

Keep getting the error

```
"Message: element click intercepted: Element <a id="pd-vote-button10919978" class="css-vote-button pds-vote-button">...</a> is not clickable at point (243, 855). Other element would receive the click: <div id="onetrust-policy">...</div>"
```

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

first_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pds-answer10919978']/div[72]/div/label/span"))).click()

second_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pd-vote-button10919978']"))).click()
```

How do I bypass the iv `id="onetrust-policy"` and make it click o the element that I want? I've tried finding the element by `ID`, `Class`, and `XPath` so far.

Comment: What is `first_button` in UI ? how does it appear ?

Comment: you may need to interact with that div first... what does it show?  (I'm guessing it's one of those "do you accept cookies/terms of site" type modal dialogs.)

Comment: @pcalkins thank you